# ERROR in main-es2015.0e205048d3a6c0966c34.js from Terser after installing angular-slickgrid

Tags: angular, webpack, slickgrid

```
ERROR in main-es2015.0e205048d3a6c0966c34.js from Terser
TypeError: e.contains_this is not a function
```

I got this error while running `ng prod --build` in my angular 9 code.This code was running fine two days ago.Today I installed `angular-slickgrid` and after that when I'm going to build,I got this error.My angular-cli version :9.0.5 and terser version :4.5.1 and terser-webpack-plugin version : 2.3.3.
Below is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
 import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from 
'@angular/common/http';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
 import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform- 
 browser/animations';
import { AngularSlickgridModule } from 'angular-slickgrid';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    MaterialFileuploadComponent,
    UploadDataComponent,
    AuditTrailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularSlickgridModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I assume you did not look at the opened GitHub issues, if you did, you would probably have found this [issue](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/413) which explains it, I don't really have much time to spend on this and I'd be happy to receive help on the matter.

Comment: you need to add `@dynamic` as comment on top of `NgModule`, see this [Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid/wiki/HOWTO---Step-by-Step#angular-7-1) mention